# IntComponent() error

Tags: java, string

I have a string in one frame named uname.

```
uname = usrNameTxt.getText();
char[] pword = pwordTxt.getPassword();
String password = new String(pword);
```

and pointed that to the next frame by

```
 this.dispose();
 new SectionsFclty(uname).setVisible(true);
```

and in my another one (shown below) frame want the String uname...

```
  public SectionsFclty() {
    initComponents();   
}

 public SectionsFclty(String uname) {
    initComponents();
    jLabelUsername.setText(uname);
}
```

But in my second frame (SectionsFclty.java) error comes in

```
  private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabelUsername = new javax.swing.JLabel();..............

 }  // shows an error now
```

following error

```
  error: illegal start of expression
private void initComponents() {
            new SectionsFclty().setVisible(true);
```

required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: You really need to pass `SectionsFclty` constructor a string everywhere you create a new `SectionsFclty`, not just the first time. Its signature says `public SectionsFclty(String uname)`; that means it expects a string, always. By looking at the error I'd say you do not actually have a `public SectionsFclty() { initComponents();}` version, even though there's one in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the constructor to `SectionsFclty` is expecting a `String` parameter, make sure to pass it along, something like this:

```
new SectionsFclty("some string").setVisible(true);
```

Another idea: make sure that the `SectionsFclty` class *really* has a no-args constructor. The code posted in the question has it, but if the real code had it the error shown could not happen. Remember: a no-args constructor is provided implicitly, but if a different constructor is declared, then the no-arg constructor must be explicitly declared, if it's needed.

Comment: It has default constructor as well

Comment: @JigarJoshi I'm not sure that the code posted in the question is the real one, it might be the case that OP's true code only has one constructor. Otherwise the error mentioned wouldn't occur.